# Lumen (5.8.12) - Multiple optional paramter with prefix

Tags: php, routes, lumen, prefix, optional-parameters

I am trying to create an endpoint like this:

```
/most-popular/language/{language}[/max/{max}[/page/{page}]]
```

It's working perfectly if I create two separates routes:

```
/most-popular/language/en/max/10
/most-popular/language/en/max/10/page/2
```

But I can't do this:

```
/most-popular/language/en/page/2
```

How can I set my route in order to be able to use multiple optional parameters based on prefix?

```
$router->get(
    '/most-popular/language/{language}[/max/{max}[/page/{page}]]', array(
    'as' => 'most-popular',
    'uses' => 'MyController@myMethod'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do this directly. The route matcher is quite strict. You might be able to cheat though and declare all the possible incarnations of the routes.

```php
$callback = function (Request $request) {
    $defaults = [
        'language' => 'language/en',
        'max' => 'max/10',
        'page' => 'page/1'
    ];
    $language = $request->route('language', $defaults['language']);
    $max = $request->route('max', $defaults['max']);
    $page = $request->route('page', $defaults['page']);
    dd($language, $max, $page);
    // Some string splitting may be required
};


$router->get('/most-popular',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{page:page/\d+}',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{max:max/\d+}',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{language:language/\w+}',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{language:language/\w+}/{max:max/\d+}',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{language:language/\w+}/{page:page/\d+}',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{max:max/\d+}/{page:page/\d+}',$callback);
$router->get('/most-popular/{language:language/\w+}/{max:max/\d+}/{page:page/\d+}',$callback);
```

Admittedly I didn't actually try this on Lumen but in Laravel (using equivalent syntax) but if I'm reading the docs correctly it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read the doc about routes and I only found the case in which there is one and only one [optional] parameter. I asked because I am pretty sure I made the same thing working with an other framework.